# Customer name incomplete on order confirmation

Tags: email, magento, transactions, confirmation

Came across the following during a project:
Customer fills out his/her name during checkout: **Firstname Middlename Lastname**

The confirmation email sent contains incomplete name in the form of "**Firstname Lastname**" on the first sentence of the confirmation

I looked at the mail templates and the function `order.getCustomerName()` does not seem to retrieve all the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in the customer address settings of admin.

Admin → System → configuration → Customer Configuration → Name and Address Options → Show Middle Name (initial).

Showing more than the initial in the templates is something you will have to investigate further. In the UK we keep the form simple and don't ask middle names.

Comment: OK thanks ;) Checked the settings and the middle name is turned on and this is how they like it. Will investigate the template thingie further.