# Insert not showing in Magento order e-mail

Tags: magento

When a registered customer, for example "Armin van Buuren", places an order, he gets an email with "Hello Armin Buuren". That should be "Hello Armin van Buuren". Strange thing is when he would order something as a not registered user, so he don't make an account, the name in the e-mail is displayed correctly as "Hello Armin van Buuren".

In the order_new.html for registered users, the name is generated with:

```
Hello, {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}}
```

In the order_new_guest.html for not registered customers, the name is generated with:

```
Hello, {{htmlescape var=$order.getBillingAddress().getName()}}
```

Already tried to use the guest html, but that doesn't displays the name correctly. It shows the name with the prefix, but that's not correct. It should be like "Hello, [NAME] [INSERT] [SURNAME]". Also searched on internet for this, but is seems that I am the only one with this problems?

If you know a possible solution, or what I should do or try, please let me know!
Thank you!

Comment: Looks like this is a config option as it would be classed as a middle name (even though it isn't really).   This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609100/customer-name-incomplete-on-order-confirmation-in-magento although it isn't a complete solution as is pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Hmm, I think I used the wrong keywords.. -___-

Looks pretty good. Should I use this for example whem using that code?!:
Hello, {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerFirstName() var=$order.getCustomerMiddlename() var=$order.getCustomerLastname() }}

Comment: Yes I think so but that assumes you've extended the core class that handles that, as the OP in that question has done.  Although there is a Middle name config setting my understanding based on that q&a is that the default code won't do what you need it to do, you'll need to extend it the way he has done.

Comment: Yes, sure. Will do this also in the local folder. Okay, but the code should work as I described above in the comment? Because I placed the var's after each other. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the Magento settings to don't display the middle initial form, and then edited every customer to put the insert in the surname. I think that's the best option.

Thanks for the help guys!